# Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being used warning GOOGLE CLOSURE

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I am using google closure and have defined few variables. Only in the constructor am I defining their values. While compiling the the code I get the error

```
javascript/model/errorLogger.js:42: WARNING - Suspicious code. The result of the 'getprop' operator is not being used.
==> default: [WARNING] model.ErrorLogger.prototype.errors;
```

This is the code.

```
goog.provide('model.ErrorLogger');

/**
 * @constructor
 */
model.ErrorLogger = function() {
    this.errors  =[];
    this.errorsHash = {};
}

model.ErrorLogger.prototype.errors;
model.ErrorLogger.prototype.errorsHash;
```

Why is this warning coming ? Should I mention the typedef annotation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
model.ErrorLogger.prototype.errors;
model.ErrorLogger.prototype.errorsHash;
```

have no effect - you're just referencing the properties without doing anything with them.  That's what it's warning you about - it thinks you meant to assign them to something, or pass them to a function, or anything that has some effect.

(Also, those properties won't even exist in that form - it's really not clear what you're trying to do here.)

Comment: However, if you add some JSDoc, then the compiler will understand that they are there to declare the type:

`/** @type {Array<Error>} */ model.ErrorLogger.prototype.errors;`

Answer (score -1):

You are planing to access "errors" and "errorsHash" from another "class" that's not OOP friendly :) 
You have to either define accessors for your two members or tell the compiler that your members are public (even if it's the default behavior)

```
/*
* public member  
* @public
*/
```

Adding this or declare public getter/setter for your properties WILL RESOLVE YOUR ISSUE

Comment: Who said the opposite?I only told him to "enforce" the level of visibility that's it. because by doing this the compiler will stop emitting warning about those properties that's all what i said